# Can I write php code in android?

Tags: java, php, android, html

I have some code in php and I want to write that code in my android application. php code is given bellow.

```
<?php 
     $amount = urlencode($amount);
     $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
     $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
     $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
     $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
     $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);  
     echo $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
?>
```

And I want value of `$converted_amount` in string. i don't know how to do that. If i can then tell me how can I do.

Comment: Why on the earth do you have such requirement !!!

Comment: You can write PHP code in Android but there is no guaranty that it will work.

Comment: I'd recommend writing the equivalent in java. This will also help with the rest of whatever Android application you're building

Comment: @Kedarnath.... oky dude i just want to convert USD currency in to local country. so if u have any currency converter free then tell me

Comment: @NeilLocketz.. oky bro i just want to check that its possible or not nothing else

Comment: Are you asking how this would be written in Java?

Comment: @jaydip in java you can still make web requests like this look into http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @AndrewFielden ... yes in a java can i do that..??

Comment: @NeilLocketz... yes i know that bro

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write it. But if you love php so much, create a **php script** to write your above code and some kind of **HTML** page to display and load the same in a **webview**.

I havent worked on java or android, but you must be having something equivalent to `urlencode` , `file_get_contents` and `explode` in `java`.